# Instruction Coverage with JaCoCo: Number of instructions is not correct

Tags: java, jacoco

This is a simple method to test:

```
public static boolean isPowerOfTwo(final int i) {
    return (i > 0) && (i & (i - 1)) == 0;
}
```

To get the byte code I run `javap -c` on the .class file:

```
public static boolean isPowerOfTwo(int);
  Code:
     0: iload_0
     1: ifle          14
     4: iload_0
     5: iload_0
     6: iconst_1
     7: isub
     8: iand
     9: ifne          14
    12: iconst_1
    13: ireturn
    14: iconst_0
    15: ireturn
```

As you can see, there are **16** byte code instructions.

Now I run a simple Unit-Test

```
@Test
public void testPowerOfTwoInt() {
    assertFalse(Util.isPowerOfTwo(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    assertFalse(Util.isPowerOfTwo(0));
    assertTrue(Util.isPowerOfTwo(64));
    assertTrue(Util.isPowerOfTwo(128));
    assertFalse(Util.isPowerOfTwo(-128));
}
```

But JaCoCo tells me, that `isPowerOfTwo` contains only **12** byte code instructions: [image: Instruction Coverage]

What is the reason for only 12 instead of 16 byte code instructions? The class file is generated by the Eclipse compiler. Does JaCoCo runs another class file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at your output again - there are only 12 instructions reported by `javap`:

```
public static boolean isPowerOfTwo(int);
  Code:
     0: iload_0
     1: ifle          14
//There's no 2 or 3 here...
     4: iload_0
     5: iload_0
     6: iconst_1
     7: isub
     8: iand
     9: ifne          14
//and no 10 or 11 here.
    12: iconst_1
    13: ireturn
    14: iconst_0
    15: ireturn
```

Comment: Pretty sure we've all been there at one point or another.  Glad I could help.